# Unit test case with controller as syntax giving error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am unit testing a controller
USing karma.

Test case for controller:

```
    'use strict';
fdescribe('products', function() {
    // load the controller's module
    var ctrl, scope;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('products'));
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('products', function($controllerProvider) {
            $controllerProvider.register('productsController', function($scope) {

            });
        });
    });

    describe('controller', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            angular.mock.inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                ctrl = $controller('productsController', {
                    $scope: scope
                });
            })
        });

        it('controller is set', function() {
            expect(ctrl.currentCategory).toBe("ALL_PRODUCTS");
        });
    });
});
```

I have mocked the module in which the controller is there.
The expected code here is giving error as expect undefined to be "ALL_PRODUCTS".
controller.js:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var productsController = function($rootScope, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.currentCategory = "ALL_PRODUCTS";

};

productsController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];

module.exports = productsController;
```

})();

Module.js:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
module.exports = angular.module('products', ['common.services'])
    .controller('productController', require('./controller.js'))
```

})();

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @manish expect undefined to be "ALL_PRODUCTS".

Comment: that simply means `ctrl.currentCategory` is undefined

Comment: In your module js you have 'productController' but in your test you are creating 'productsController'.

Comment: @PrinayPanday 
The 'productsController' is the name of the controller and you can look that in controller.js

Comment: Agreed but you are declaring it as 'productController' in your module.js. Have you tried console.log(ctrl) in your test? Does it show it as defined?

Comment: @PrinayPanday nope.

Comment: Try changing it to 'productsController' in your module js file.